# Need help in redirect with regular expressions SPIP -> WordPress (redirect plugin)

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I can not do a redirection of the old SPIP permalink format to a Wordpress display. I would like to redirect the address from the format:

```
/expressions/spip.php?article965&debut_article_rubrique_date=330
```

Towards :

```
/?p=965
```

I tried everything, nothing helps.
What seemed to me the closest:

```
Source URL: ^/expressions/spip.php?article([0-9]+)\.$
Target URL: /?p=$1
```

But maybe I am very far away.

Comment: Source URL: `^/expressions/spip\.php\?article(\d+)(.*?)$` and Target URL: `/?p=$1$2` ?

Comment: It works, you're awesome!
6 hours I was trying xD
Thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)